# How to distribute contents from one group of classes to another group with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, each

I have two separate `div` elements, each with an equal number of `img` elements. When the page is loaded, I want to pass the `src` attributes from `"plus"` to `"minus"` with jQuery. The first `"circle"` `src` should pass to the first `"square"` `src`, the second `"circle"` `src` should pass to the second `"square"` `src`, etc.

```
<div id="plus">
    <img class="circle" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="circle" src="three.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="minus">
    <img class="square" src="#"/>
    <img class="square" src="#"/>
    <img class="square" src="#"/>
</div>
```

What is the best way to go about doing something like this? Some sort of nested `each` function or something?

Comment: I didn't get your question. You want to pass the img src dynamically ? 
Please tell us what exactly you want to do

Comment: @Krishna9960 It is fairly simple and easy to understand what's he's asking.

Comment: Yup got it...He simply wanted to copy from one element to other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each `img` in `plus` and insert it into `minus`

1. `$("#plus .circle").each()` will loop through each image inside the "plus" div.
2. You can use the `.attr()´ to both`get`and`set` an attribute on an element.

```js
$("#plus .circle").each(function(i, x) {
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  $("#minus .square:eq(" + i + ")").attr("src", src)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plus">
  <img class="circle" src="one.jpg" />
  <img class="circle" src="two.jpg" />
  <img class="circle" src="three.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="minus">
  <img class="square" src="#" />
  <img class="square" src="#" />
  <img class="square" src="#" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#plus").find('img').each(function(i, v) {
  $("#minus").find('img').eq(i).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plus">
  <img class="circle" src="one.jpg" />
  <img class="circle" src="two.jpg" />
  <img class="circle" src="three.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="minus">
  <img class="square" src="#" />
  <img class="square" src="#" />
  <img class="square" src="#" />
</div>
```

1. Use .each() to loop the plus div
2. Use attr() to set src for minus div img